# How can i make my sub-menu show and hide when click on main item?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('.slideout-menu li').click(
        function() {
             $(this).children('.mobile-sub-menu').show();
        },
        function() {
              $(this).children('.mobile-sub-menu').hide();
    });
```

```css
.slideout-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(248, 248, 248);
  z-index: 1;
}

.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 9px 5px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #222;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
  /*border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideout-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">MANUALS</a>
        <ul class="mobile-sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SPARE PART</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHERE TO BUY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EDIT BOOK</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I add some sub-item under MANUALS main item.
What can I do to make its sub-menu hide and show when I click on its parent main item?

I try to write some jQuery code but right now only can hide the item but cannot let it show again. 
Is something wrong on my jQuery code?

Comment: Do you wish to only hide the mobile-sub-menu and than slide it up or down when you click on slideout-menu or even the .slideout-menu class has to be inviisble ? Do make the mobile-sub-menu invisble you can simple add the line                                                                              .slideout-menu .mobile-sub-menu
{
  display:none;
}                                                                                                                                               to your css

Comment: Sorry for confused. What I want is to make my sub-item show when I click on main items(MANUALS) and hide again when i click main item(MANUALS) again.

Comment: just to let you know your above code had problems with the arguments. If you use hover with your code, you will be able to see it work as hover allows you to bind elements when you enter and leave a element whereas with click you define a function to be executed each time the element is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your (show/hide) with "toggle" function like this :

```
$('.slideout-menu li').click(
    function() {
          $(this).children('.mobile-sub-menu').toggle();
});
```

And that will work fine .

Toggle function : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/